# PHP - Weird file_get_contents behavior

Tags: php, file-get-contents, behavior

When I run the first code it works well. The echo works.

```
<?php
$html = file_get_contents('https://feedback.aliexpress.com/display/productEvaluation.htm?productId=32795887882&ownerMemberId=230515078&withPictures=true&i18n=true&Page=3'); 
$dom = new domDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$images = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');
foreach ($images as $image) {
echo $image->getAttribute('src');
echo "<br>";
}
?>
```

But when I try the following code and running it with parameters nothing is returned:

*index.php?url=https://feedback.aliexpress.com/display/productEvaluation.htm?productId=32795887882&ownerMemberId=230515078&withPictures=true&i18n=true&Page=3*

```
<?php

$html = file_get_contents($_GET["url"]);
$dom = new domDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$images = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');
foreach ($images as $image) {
echo $image->getAttribute('src');
echo "<br>";
}
?>
```

Anyone got any idea?

**Update:**

Probally not the best and cleanest solution, but it works :)

```
<?
$url = urldecode($_GET['url']);
$ownerMemberId = urldecode($_GET['ownerMemberId']);
$withPictures = urldecode($_GET['withPictures']);
$page = urldecode($_GET['Page']);

$newurl = $url . "&ownerMemberId=" . $ownerMemberId . 
"&withPictures=true&i18n=true&Page=" . $page;

$html = file_get_contents($newurl);
$dom = new domDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$images = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');

foreach ($images as $image) {
echo "<img src='";
echo $image->getAttribute('src');
echo "'>";
echo "<br>";
}

?>
```

Comment: Take a look at what `$_GET['url']` contains, e.g. just do an `echo $_GET['url']`.

Comment: it should be `index.php?url=https%3A%2F%2Ffeedback.aliexpress.com%2Fdisplay%2FproductEvaluation.htm%3FproductId%3D32795887882%26ownerMemberId%3D230515078%26withPictures%3Dtrue%26i18n%3Dtrue%26Page%3D3`  then decode it in PHP as suggested by @Tristup check out https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding for more details

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please decode the url as it is sending another url.

```
$url = urldecode($_GET['url']);
$html = file_get_contents($url);
$dom = new domDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$images = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');

foreach ($images as $image) {
    echo $image->getAttribute('src');
    echo "<br>";
}
```

Hope that works for you.

Comment: Thank you! It almost works. The first part works:
"https://feedback.aliexpress.com/display/productEvaluation.htm?productId=32795887882" but it loses the parameters when the "&" comes in. "&ownerMemberId=230515078&withPictures=true&i18n=true&Page=3" disappears.

Comment: $page=urldecode($_GET['Page']); it will do for Page and for other just replicate the same

Comment: Thank you. See the update in my OP. Probably not the best way but it works! :)